# How can I compare two different list classes?

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm wondering if it is possible to compare two list from different classes

Let's suppose I have a `list1<A>`, and a `list2<B>`. Is there a way to create a list which contains the same nameA and nameB elements?, I mean, check if nameA and nameB are equals, and if yes add the item to a new list.

```
Class A{
  String nameA;
  int id;
}

Class B{
  String nameB;
  int id;
}
```

Thanks in andvance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create a method in class which compare string and you can iterate through all items and compare it.

following code will help you more.

Create class Like below.

```
class A {
  String nameA;
  int id;
  A({this.nameA, this.id});

  bool compareB(A a, B b) {
    if (a.nameA == b.nameB) {
      return true;
    }
    return false;
  }
}

class B {
  String nameB;
  int id;
  B({this.nameB, this.id});
  bool compareB(A a, B b) {
    if (a.nameA == b.nameB) {
      return true;
    }
    return false;
  }
}
```

creating list and compare.

```
 List<A> aList = [
      A(id: 1, nameA: 'hello'),
      A(id: 2, nameA: 'Flutter'),
      A(id: 3, nameA: 'World'),
    ];
    List<B> bList = [
      B(id: 1, nameB: 'hello'),
      B(id: 2, nameB: 'Programming'),
      B(id: 3, nameB: 'World'),
    ];
    List result = [];
    for (int i = 0; i < aList.length; i++) {
      for (int j = 0; j < bList.length; j++) {
        if (aList[i].compareB(aList[i], bList[j])) {
          result.add(aList[i]);
          result.add(bList[j]);
        }
      }
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < result.length; i++) {
      if (result[i].runtimeType == A) {
        print(result[i].nameA);
      } else if (result[i].runtimeType == B) {
        print(result[i].nameB);
      }
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I have a doubt, will the resut list be dynamic?

Comment: Yes definitely. Check how I printed data.

Answer (score 0):

While there maybe different ways to do this, such as the answer by Viren suggests you can also use a package that does it for you [collection](https://pub.dev/packages/collection)